# OGR: Meaning of "2.5D extension as per 99-402"

Tags: ogr

I'm looking at the enum defs in `ogr_core.h`.  I see a bunch with comments that read:

> 2.5D extension as per 99-402.

What in the world does that mean?  Presumably it's referencing a spec or RFC?

```
typedef enum 
{
  ...
  wkbPoint25D = 0x80000001, /**< 2.5D extension as per 99-402 */
  wkbLineString25D = 0x80000002, /**< 2.5D extension as per 99-402 */
  wkbPolygon25D = 0x80000003, /**< 2.5D extension as per 99-402 */
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference is almost certainly to an OGC specification or change request for a specification, but I'm not able to find that specific one on the OGC web site. You can read more about it at [GDAL web site](http://home.gdal.org/projects/opengis/twohalfdsf.html) (from a [Frank W. email](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2010-March/024043.html)) or by looking in the OGC Simple Features spec.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks.  This page (http://www.gdal.org/ogr/) contains a link to Adam's 2.5 D Simple Features Proposal (OGC 99-402r2), which is at the link you mention, http://home.gdal.org/projects/opengis/twohalfdsf.html.

Answer (score 1):

Here is explanation from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2.5D_%28machining%29)

> A 2.5D image is a simplified three-dimensional (x, y, z) surface representation that contains at most one depth (z) value for every point in the (x, y) plane.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to just take a snippet from the site and post it here as a quote so people don't have to follow the link.

Comment: @NathanW Good point, I've taken the liberty to edit it

Answer (score 1):

This mean **"Z values in Simple Features co-ordinates"** which was originally proposed by **Adam Gawne-Cain** in **1999** as *Simple Features Revision Proposal*.

For sake of historical background, here is Martin Daly's post with reference to Adam Gawne-Cain's documents which use to be available from OGC site, thread
[[postgis-devel] OGC WKB/T - PGIS EWKB/T](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-devel/2004-December/000702.html) and another post in the same thread has the  original [**99-402r2.pdf** attached](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-devel/2004-December/000695.html).

That is the only existing online source of the original document I'm aware of.
Reading it should answer where does the **2.5D** geometries implemented in numerous software packages (GDAL/OGR, PostGIS, Safe FME, etc.) come from.